# Solve this conditional probability for this p.c.f

Tags: real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series, conditional-probability

In my lecture's note, literally said in the title, there is a question like the below.

$P(x=n) = {4 \over {(n^2 -1)n}}$ for $n =2,3,4,5,...$.

Find the $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} P(x \leq 2n \vert n<x)$

---

He doesn't any suggest his solution, only claimed the answer is $3 \over 4$ But, Whenever I did it over and over again, I couldn't got that.

Here is my solution.

$P(x=n) = 2\{ {1\over n-1} + {1\over n+1} - {2\over n}\}$

Then, $P(n \lt x \leq m ) = P(x=n +1) + P(x=n+2) + ... + P(x=m) = 2 \{ {1\over n} - {1\over n+1} - {1\over m} + {1\over m+1}\} $

So,  $\lim\limits_{m\to \infty} P(n \lt x \leq m ) = P(n \lt x) = 2 \{ {1\over n} - {1\over n+1}\}$ $= {2 \over {n(n+1)}}$

Plus, $P(n \lt x \leq 2n ) = 2 \{ {1\over n} - {1\over n+1} - {1\over 2n} + {1\over 2n+1}\} = 2 \{ {{n^2+3n+1}\over n(n+1)(2n+1)}\} $

Hence, $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} P(x \leq 2n \vert n<x) = {{ P(n \lt x \leq 2n ) }\over{P(n \lt x)}} = \infty$

Which point did I have a mistake? Any help would be appreciated.

I carefully speculate his question is non-sense because I can't find any numerical error in my solution. :(

Comment: Your calculation cannot be correct as the conditional probability must be bounded above by $1$

Comment: @Henry, without the calculation then, Is the idea right for solving it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation cannot be correct as the conditional probability must be bounded above by $1$

Once you have $$P(n \lt x \leq m ) = 2 \left( {1\over n} - {1\over n+1} - {1\over m} + {1\over m+1}\right)$$
I would have thought the next steps could be $$P(n \lt x \leq 2n ) = 2 \left( {1\over n} - {1\over n+1} - {1\over 2n} + {1\over 2n+1}\right)= \frac{3n+1}{n(n+1)(2n+1)}$$
$$P(n \lt x ) = 2 \left( {1\over n} - {1\over n+1} \right)= {2\over n(n+1)} $$
$$P(n \lt x \leq 2n\mid n \lt x ) = \frac{3n+1}{4n+2}$$ and that last expression tends to $\frac34$ as $n$ increases

Comment: Beautiful! I find my mistake thanks to you. :)